# Checked div influence other divs written before it

Tags: html, css

I have problem which actually is difficult for me to be defined, so sorry for the name of topic. Coming to the issue... I have few inputs next to each other. Like:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-2"/>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-3"/>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-4"/>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-5"/>
            <a href="#"></a>
```

and in css

```
input#st-control-3:checked ~  input {
    left:-200%; }

    input#st-control-3:checked ~  a {
    left:-200%; }
```

I want to move other inputs by clicking on for example #st-control-3 . It works , however only on elements (in my case inputs) which are written after #st-control-3, so in my example the effect does not appear on #st-control-2.

So the question is how to influence on the element which is not parrent or child and it is written before active element.

I hope that it is quite clear what I wrote.

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, you cannot traverse *up* the DOM with CSS. You would need to use Javascript to accomplish something like that.

Comment: It is what i thought... I am JS beginner so the question is how such script should look like ? Something like this ? :

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
       $("#st-control-2").click(
            function(){
                $("input").css('left','-200%');
                
            }
         
             
          );
      });

   </script>

Answer (score 0):

Ok I add class to < a > because I need one < a > to stay and I did it by JS using code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#st-control-3").click(function(){

                $(".panel").css('left','-200%');

            }); 

        });
```

Everything works but I have problem with "back button"... how to create next function which would return .panel to default position ?